# Why does a particular circuit breaker keep tripping?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My MCB (Main Circuit Board) has a circuit breaker for each room and AC is directly connected with RCB (Residual Circuit Breaker). There is a room that trips its breaker at least once a fortnight.

Also, there's a circuit breaker, for a TV showcase which has TV, internet router, and set top box connected in it and the it trips once in a while. Whenever this one trips, the power adapter for the internet router gets wasted and becomes unusable. I opened the socket and positively confirmed there's no short in it, additionally, there's no black mark in power adapter or socket.

Any ideas why it is happening and what I should do next?

**FYI:**

My house has 3 phase connection

Please find the pics of MCB here.

It has 8 miniature circuit breakers and what we see on the right is the RCD (Residual Current Device) I guess.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**
The room which frequently trips , burnt a plug last night. Please find the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When the plug started burning at midnight , I fortunately woke up and went up to the MCB and turned off the circuit breaker manually.

The circuit breaker provides connection to Water heater in bath room , two tube lights , a zero watts night light , one incandescent bulb light and two round LED slim blight )

At the time of the incident , there was a plug from extension box which connects to a laptop and it's 32 inch screen was on and zero watts night light was on. That's all.

Any ideas why something happens with this room always like tripping twice in fortnight.

Someone please explain me what needs to be done to prevent any serious future issue.

Comment: Using an extension cable, you could try plugging each individual device into a power socket in another room to identify which one is causing the issue.

Comment: You mean to say to plug the device using an extension cord to the room where AC is ?

Comment: No, use the extension to plug the the television, internet router etc individually into a socket in another room.  If the breaker for the other room trips, you know which device is causing it.

Comment: If these are "plain" circuit breakers (i.e. no GFCI/AFCI/RCD/RCBO), then when the trips happen, it because the circuit is overloaded. If they're one of the "advanced" breakers, then it's either a simple overload _or_ it's detecting one of the critical conditions that will trip the breaker. Do any of the involved breakers have a "TEST" button you can push? If you're not sure, [edit] your question to include a picture of the breaker panel and tell us which breaker(s) are the ones causing issues.

Comment: @FreeMan - I have updated the question with photos of MCB

Comment: Which breaker is tripping?

Comment: Tripper number 6 is for TV panel ( TV, Internet router, Set top box etc..) and Tripper number 5 is for the room which I believed AC was also connected with but when I checked in fact AC is not connected with any of the individual trippers .. even though it's in the room it's not connected with room's tripper. It's connected with global tripper

Comment: @FreeMan - Should I disconnect all the electronic appliances and press the **TEST** button in my MCB ? How can I diagnose ?

Comment: Shut one problem circuit breaker off, and then give us a list of all heat-making appliances which lost power. By "heat making appliances" I mean appliances which make or move a considerable amount of heat. We don't care about TVs, set top boxes, anything with a wall wart, or anything that doesn't get all that hot.  Just leave those off the list.  We are looking for things that take 1000 watts or more.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Vacuum cleaner , Bath room Water heater ,  OTG Microwave oven, Washing machine, Refridgerator,Slow speed mono block water pump , Kettle, Iron box & Sandwich maker.

Comment: Can you add pix of the electrical nameplates of the bathroom water heater, microwave, washing machine, kettle, water pump, iron box, and sandwich maker?  (but honestly I think we have the data we need to answer lol).

Comment: yeah :) I will take pix and update the post. Is there anyway to find if any particular appliance is causing it ? like pressing the Test button in RCD and see if it trips or is there any way I can test inidivual socket with something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found your problem.  Look at the list of appliances on this single circuit.  And their amperages @ your household voltage of 230V.

- Vacuum cleaner - 1-4 amps
- Bathroom sink water heater - 8-20 amps (see nameplate)
- Washing machine - 1-6 amps
- 1500 watt OTG/microwave - 6 amps (keyboard warriors: this is 230V)
- Refrigerator: 1 amp
- Water pump - 2-6 amps (see nameplate)
- Kettle = 9-12 amps
- Iron box = 4-8 amps
- Sandwich grill = 6-10 amps

Now look at the circuit breaker handle. I bet it says 13 or 16 amps.  See the problem?

You are simply overloading the circuit by running too many loads at the same time.

The cure is to stop overloading the circuit!

If you cannot live with that, then it is time to call an electrician in to have some additional circuits added.  It looks like you have the panel capacity to support more circuits.  You should start by pulling the bathroom heater and pump onto separate circuit(s). The chef can probably figure out how to not run too many cooking appliances at once, but clearly the bathroom heater and/or pump is something they cannot manage.

In the USA all kitchens, even in the smallest flats, are required to have 2 circuits merely for plug-in countertop appliances. That's not a bad idea, honestly.

Comment: Could you place take a look into the updated question please ?

Comment: Herewith I have listed all the appliances with power consumption. Could you check and let me know your suggestion please ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Ac1n4SJiBAL6SPocB4JqClSNBwBLXQ-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106354200081003577526&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @CuriousMan I seeca world of loads on the B2 circuit, and other circuits barely loaded at all and could be combined.   A 5000 W load should simply not be on the same circuit as anything else.  That and a couple other loads need a dedicated circuit.    It's quite possible that your plug melt was not a fault of the plug, but far too much current being pulled through the socket.

Comment: I asked my electrician to remove Air Conditioner from B2 Circuit now , it will have it's own dedicated connection but there are no more trippers available so he said he connected that without any separate tripper. If there's any problem with this AC then the Main tripper in which all other trippers are connected will trip. You can probably see the big rectangular tripper in the above picture